# How do you get the list of photos for a Facebook news feed post using the Graph API?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you call the Facebook Graph API to get your News Feed (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/me/home) how do you get the list of photos for a post of "type": "photo"?

Example of data returned for this post type:

> "picture":
>   "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs476.ash2/74934_488508013245942_500295932442_7503613_3825747_s.jpg",
>
> "link":
>   "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=48423348508015942&set=a.488507985942.296814.500295942",
>
> "name": "Recent Misc Fun...",
>
> "caption": "16 new photos",

The picture URL will give you the "cover" image for the set of images that may be included in the post.  The link URL will take you to the Facebook page for those photos.

I'd like to know how to get an array of URLs for all the photos in the post.

It appears the link URL may have some information encoded regarding the relevant photos for the post (set=a.488507985942.296814.500295942), but I don't know how to interpret this.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the ObjectId from field "object_id" for a specific post from your news feed

Use this object_id value to make a separate Graph API call as follows -

https://graph.facebook.com/10152199489086727?fields=images&access_token=

This will return the list of images of varying sizes for this post.

Example output:

```
{
"images": [
    {
        "height": 462, 
        "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/10302057_10152199489086727_707407897349696496_n.jpg", 
        "width": 616
    }, 
    {
        "height": 320, 
        "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/p320x320/10302057_10152199489086727_707407897349696496_n.jpg", 
        "width": 426
    },.... ..
], 
"created_time": "2014-07-23T18:15:16+0000", 
"id": "10152199489086727"
}
```